# Installing Teamspeak

Tags: software-installation, teamspeak

I want to install Teamspeak and found [this](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/TeamSpeak_3) tutorial. When I go to the official TeamSpeak Download Site [here](http://www.teamspeak.com/?page=downloads) I have several options to download for Linux. I downloaded the AMD64 client package (using fully updated 64bit Ubuntu). I went and checked the "Start as Program" checkbox in the properties of the .run file. Sadly when I started it with a doubleclick gedit opened it (and crashed after a while).
So I navigated to the folder and did: ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.15.1.run
It worked and I had a folder with Teamspeak in my Downloads folder.
But although I checked the "Start as Program" checkbox for the ts3client_linux_amd64 it does nothing.. If I rightclick and choose "Run as application" nothing happens (at least I see nothing).
The ts3client_runscript.sh opens in gedit beneath enabling the said checkbox.

Any way to get it working? Don't know how to run these over terminal (pretty new user).

Mind that the checkbox titles etc. are freely translated from German to English.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: should you use something like **sudo apt-get install teamspeak** or actually use the Ubuntu software center to get that? right guys?

Comment: if searching for teamspeak in the software center I don't get a result (beneath other programs). so I decided to install it manually and looked for a tutorial

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Also, do you have the multiverse repository enabled?

Comment: the latest fully updated. so Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. 
I have the checkbox (multiverse) checked so I think it is enabled.

Comment: @raverrebel try the command, it must work, open a terminal using the combination of **Ctrl + Alt + T** keys and write the bold text in the first comment, it will install

Comment: tried it but he can't found the package teamspeak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have scripts set to launch or ask.

Open `Nautilus` goto `Edit` ➤ `Preferences`

Click the `Behavior` tab and underneath `Executable Text Files` select either `Run...` or `Ask...`

If you choose `Ask` it'll prompt you with the options to <kbd>Run in Terminal</kbd>, <kbd>Display</kbd>, <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, or <kbd>Run</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Since newest Teamspeak version was removed from the repository only way to install right now is manual install

Try this

Create a new file name it "Teamspeak3.desktop" and edit the file and add this

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=Teamspeak 3 Client   
Exec=/<RouteTo>/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh   
Type=Application  
Icon=/route/to/icon.png  
Version=3
```

Simpler Solution

Save and Try opening it
Source
http://codetunnel.com/how-to-add-teamspeak-3-to-the-unity-launcher-in-ubuntu/

Comment: thank you. this was not exactly my question but came handy :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with this, as I was, try following this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhG5H8KwZRM

My first attempt wouldn't run, so I used this method. You need to install Arronax, it's a program that makes 'a starter'. That's as much as I know about it but it worked for me.

Here are the commands for the Arronax program.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arronax

Comment: Whilst the video may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of its method here, and provide the link for reference.